# How to find element count from child to parent with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a slight issue where i need to count nest level of elements.
Problem is that parent element can hold multiple child elements and child elements can have their own child elements.

Please see from where i want to start count (marked with text "I start here").

HTML:

```
<div class="main_set">
    <div class="child_set">
        <div class="child_set">
            <div class="child_set">I start here!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child_set"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child_set">
        <div class="child_set"></div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried couple things to get count 3.
For example my last attempt:

```
$(this).closest('.main_set').find('.child_set');
```

This one obviously returns 6 tho counting all child_sets.

How to count `child_set` elements from start place to `main_set` taking into account only nesting. So basically in my example how to get count 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) from `this` to find all parents (with a special selector); for the length you have to add one for the current.

```
alert($(this).parents('.child_set').length + 1);
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/G8WtL/1/).

Comment: Wow, thanks i usually tend to over complicate things. This working great. Will close after time for accept runs out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count all `child_set` starting from div which says `I start here!`, you would do this:

```
$(this).parents('.child_set').length + 1
```

This would give you `3`. The `1` is added because your div with text `I start here!` has also `child_set` class.

**Documentation:**

- http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: @arma: Sure no problem, spent some time in understanding your question :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call stopPropagation or it'll call the parent events because they have the same class `child_set`.

```
 $('.main_set').on('click', '.child_set', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log($(this).parents('.child_set').andSelf().length);
    });
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/LHqY2/)

Look this other demo: [**Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/LHqY2/1/%3Cbr%3E)
Here you can see that it works for any div.

Answer (score 0):

use `.children()` instead of `.find()`

[here clearly said](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.